# Upload a image with fetch

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, laravel-5, redux, fetch

I have a form defined:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The handler for the submit event is defined as such:

```
handleSubmit(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var FormData = require('form-data');
        var form = new FormData();

        form.append('nome', this.refs.name.value);
        form.append('phone', this.refs.phone.value);
        form.append('address', this.refs.address.value);
        form.append('mail', this.refs.mail.value);
        form.append('type', 'file');
        form.append('photo', this.refs.photo.value);

        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(fetchByArray(form));
    } }
```

fetchByArray(form):

```
export function fetchByArray(form) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return fetch(`http://my_domain/api`, {
            method: "POST", body: form })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveByQuerystring1(json)));
    } }
```

This works if all the parameters are strings but if I try to specify a file, I get an error as my api handler doesn't get the file.

On the backend `$request->file('photo')` is empty. What could be my issue here?

Comment: You probably have to specify a different option in your form data, like shown here https://github.com/github/fetch#file-upload

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898

Answer (score 0):

You need to read http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html rules for file sending api. We have lot of restrictions in client file system related operation.

I will describe how it works for me using React-Redux-Saga

1. I have input type file like this:

```html
<input
    type="file"
    onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

2. And onChange handler (uploading right after file chosen)

```js
this.props.registerFile(this.state.id, event.target.files[0]);
```

3. Creating request for file upload

```js
const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file.get('file')); //event.target.files[0] data going here
    
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
      };

const result = yield call(xhrRequest, requestURL, requestOptions);

function request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then((response) => {
      let result = response;
      return result;
    })
    .then((data) => ({ data }))
    .catch((err) => ({ err }));
```